# How can I modify regular expression to validate domain properly?

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I found the following regex:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
```

on this site:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

and it works great (matches 99.99% of actual emails), with one exception. It allows you to append anything you want after the domain.

example:

```
test does not match
test@domain does not match
test@domain.com does match
test@domain.co.uk does match
test@domain.comdsaf#()%@dsf,25ljsafdlfkjj&45234^\/3258afsd still matches
```

I also only want to validate a single email at a time, so the following string should not match, despite being valid in an email client:
test@domain.com;test2@domain.com

This is being used by javascript.

Comment: What if you add `^` on the beggining and `$` at the end ?

Comment: This is how I validate emails: send an email, wait for confirmation; email validated.

Comment: RFC 822 email addresses are not good candidates for regular expression matching. See http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html for a more comprehensive (and accurate) expression.

Comment: Your regex matches correctly this part highlighted `test@domain.comdsaf`#()%@dsf,25ljsafdlfkjj&45234^\/3258afsd. It does not match the un-highlighted part. I don't know what you mean by it still matches. You are trying to match the valid email aren't you?

Comment: @sln you are correct. what i was looking for was for the entire string to match, not just a portion of it. DontVoteMeDown made a suggestion that makes total sense now that I see it.

Comment: Doesn't match `me@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

`/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/`

I just added in the dollar sign at the end, indicating that you are expecting the end of the input at that point.